# Load a service in a FormBuilderInterface class

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony service which loads a list of available languages from my database.

I have a FormBuilderInterface class where i define my form structure:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class UserProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // $this->get('locations')->getCountries()

        echo 'options<pre>';
        print_r($options);
        echo '</pre>';

        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('surname')
            ->add('birthdate')
            ->add('country', 'choice', 
                array(
                    'choices'  => $listOfCountries, // i want this !!
                    'choices_as_values' => true
                )
            )
            ->add('province')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('occupation')
            ->add('interests')
            ->add('languages')
            ->add('aboutMe')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\UserProfile'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'userbundle_userprofile';
    }
}
```

I tried to load my Locations service in my FormBuilderInterface with:

$this->get('locations);

But it doesn't works.

I have searching in the Internet but i haven't found anything about this.

How i can do it?

Thanks you!

Comment: Define your form type as a service which in turn allows you to inject whatever additional services you might need: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service.  The link is for S2.8/S3.x.  Select S2.7 if applicable as there are some slight differences.

Comment: IMO,  and it is MO only,  throwing services into form classes is terrible design.  you introduce dependencies that would be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't be trying to call a service inside the formType. Inject what you need through the controller.

**controller** (note the 3rd param)

```
$form = $this->createForm( new UserProfileType(), $entity, array('locations' => $locations ) );
```

**then in your formType class**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $listOfCountries = $options['locations']

    // ......
}

/*
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\UserProfile',
        'locations' => array()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro! It is all that i needed!

Comment: you're welcome.  good luck with it.  try to keep your services to a well designed minimum, they all add overhead that after a while can show things down.